# Visual Studio 2017 crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The crashing is largely occurring when I start adding reports to different projects. The more I do, the worse it gets, but it typically doesn't take long before it freezes up.

My first thought was to check Event Viewer to see what I was getting, but I'm not quite sure what to make of it (SSRS developer, not thoroughly experienced with VS troubleshooting or .NET in general).

[image]

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr)
   at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight()
   at System.Drawing.Font.get_Height()
   at System.Windows.Forms.GroupBoxRenderer.DrawThemedGroupBoxWithText(System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle, System.String, System.Drawing.Font, System.Drawing.Color, System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.GroupBoxState)
   at System.Windows.Forms.GroupBoxRenderer.DrawGroupBox(System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle, System.String, System.Drawing.Font, System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.GroupBoxState)
   at System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs, Int16)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPrint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPrintClient(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Then there's another Error 1 second after this one:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 15.9.28307.1093, time stamp: 0x5e93584b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.997, time stamp: 0xd5511be4
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x001140b2
Faulting process id: 0x73d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d68ac284d7cc95
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 13d4e226-4630-4215-aab4-e8d382080996
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The only extension I'm using is Visual SVN. Something I have already tried is removing it, but I still get crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Never could figure out why it crashes, but I at least appear to have resolved my issue by running VS 2019 and installing the MS SSRS extension. I was able to load my pre-existing solution, and while I had to manually reload my projects, it's working well so far. Hope this helps others.